# Should I defragment my hard disk before installing using WUBI?

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-xp, compatibility

Is it advisable to defragment my hard disk before using WUBI? Is there any other precautions that I should  take before using WUBI ? My os is windows XP-32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed defragment your hard disk before installing ubuntu. You should also make two backups of all your files and make sure you *know* what you are doing. In other words, read everything on WUBI install you can find on this website.

Comment: Can you please tell me the basic avenues that I should look into before installing using WUBI.

Comment: Please see the [official installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use WUBI; do a real install
2. Get rid of XP while you are at it; it is about to reach end of life and will no longer get security patches.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are advising me against WUBI?

Comment: @user220789, it has always been rather problematic and is no longer supported and won't work on recent machines with UEFI and/or Windows 7+

Comment: You say that wubi is no longer supported, by that do you mean that it is no longer capable of working as an installer? I mean its still available for download here , this is really confusing.

Comment: @user220789, I mean it is no longer supported or recommended for use, so don't use it.